# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') when trying to use my library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, react-hooks

I am trying to build my first component library, and I am facing this error on the client side when trying to use it.
I've done some reading on this issue, and it seems that it is usually caused by on of two things:

1. using he useState hook outside of a component.
2. Having two different versions of React?

I'm certain that I am not doing the 1st. All my useStates are definitely only called inside components. About the second, I am not sure. This is my first time trying to build a library, and tbh my understanding of how to define package.json dependencies isn't great.

This is an example component (I have one package which is base components, then another package that consumes the base components library and styles them). This is an example for one of the base components:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import {StyledButton} from "../StyledButton";
import { CommentFormBaseProps } from "./interface";

function CommentFormBase({
  user,
  width,
  dir = "ltr",
  buttonMarginTop,
  buttonColor,
  buttonText = "Post comment",
  buttonBorderRadius,
  buttonFontColor,
  buttonFontSize,
  buttonFontWeight,
  buttonPaddingX,
  buttonPaddingY,
  buttonFullWidth,
  buttonShadow,
  textareaPlaceholder = "Write a comment...",
  textareaBackgroundColor = "white",
  textareaTextColor = "#111827",
  textareaDefaultRows = 5,
  textareaBorderColor,
  textareaPaddingLeft,
  textareaPaddingRight,
  textareaPaddingTop,
  textareaPaddingBottom,
  textareaBorderRadius,
}: CommentFormBaseProps) {
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  function handleSubmit() {
    if (isSubmitting) return;

    if (!user) {
      setError("Please login first");
      return;
    }

    // TODO make a call to create a comment with the user, body and itemIdentifier
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ width: width || "100%" }} dir={dir}>
      <div
        className="shadow"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: textareaBackgroundColor,
          borderColor: textareaBorderColor,
          paddingLeft: textareaPaddingLeft,
          paddingRight: textareaPaddingRight,
          paddingTop: textareaPaddingTop,
          paddingBottom: textareaPaddingBottom,
          borderRadius: textareaBorderRadius,
        }}
      >

        <textarea
          rows={textareaDefaultRows}
          value={body}
          onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}
          placeholder={textareaPlaceholder}
          required
          className="px-0 w-full text-sm border-0 focus:ring-0 focus:outline-none placeholder-gray-300"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: textareaBackgroundColor,
            color: textareaTextColor,
            paddingLeft: textareaPaddingLeft ? textareaPaddingLeft * 0.5 : 0,
            paddingRight: textareaPaddingRight ? textareaPaddingRight * 0.5 : 0,
          }}
        />
        <div className="flex justify-end">
          <StyledButton
            type="button"
            text={buttonText}
            mt={buttonMarginTop}
            buttonColor={buttonColor}
            borderRadius={buttonBorderRadius}
            fontSize={buttonFontSize}
            fontWeight={buttonFontWeight}
            fontColor={buttonFontColor}
            paddingX={buttonPaddingX}
            paddingY={buttonPaddingY}
            full={buttonFullWidth}
            shadow={buttonShadow}
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            disabled={isSubmitting}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-end">
          {error && (
            <p
              className="text-sm text-right"
              style={{
                color: "red",
                marginTop: 4,
                marginRight: 4,
              }}
            >
              {error}
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CommentFormBase;
```

Then in my second package (the one which consumes these base components), this is a components which consumes he component above and throws the error):

```
import React from "react";
import { CommentFormBase, CommentFormBaseProps } from "@replyke/base";

function CommentFormMilan(props: CommentFormBaseProps) {
  return (
    <CommentFormBase
      textareaBackgroundColor="white"
      textareaBorderColor="#E5E7EB"
      textareaTextColor="#111827"
      buttonColor="#2563EB"
      textareaBorderRadius={8}
      textareaPaddingTop={8}
      textareaPaddingBottom={8}
      textareaPaddingLeft={8}
      textareaPaddingRight={8}
      buttonPaddingX={12}
      buttonPaddingY={8}
      buttonFontWeight={500}
      buttonFontColor="white"
      buttonFontSize={14}
      buttonBorderRadius={8}
      buttonMarginTop={8}
      buttonShadow
      avatarBorderRadius={32}
      avatarSize={24}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

export default CommentFormMilan;
```

For the first package (base components) this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "@replyke/base",
  "version": "1.3.5",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/replyke"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "rollup-build": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind-input.css -o ./tailwind-dist/tailwind-output.css --watch",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "author": "Yanay",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.7",
    "flowbite": "^1.6.5",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.4.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "rollup": "^3.23.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.3.0",
    "storybook": "^7.0.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "tslib": "^2.5.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

Then this is my package.json for the second package of the styled components:

```
{
  "name": "@replyke/styled",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "rollup-build": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind-input.css -o ./tailwind-dist/tailwind-output.css --watch",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6007",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@replyke/base": "^1.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^3.23.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.3.0",
    "storybook": "^7.0.18",
    "tslib": "^2.5.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "author": "Yanay",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```